# Find all hardcoded strings in React/Node project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, react-i18next

My team and I took over a legacy project with only partially implemented i18n. Now we'd like to find all hardcoded strings in the project. Can you guys think of a regex, plugin (VS Code other other) or script/tool for this?

Interestingly, searching for this issue turns up mostly desktop programming languages.

Comment: When saying hardcoded strings, do you mean text that is not used by i18n like `<p> some text blah blah </p>` or actual value texts like `<SomeComponent value={"foo"} />` ?

Comment: Unfortunately both.

Comment: Okay then it's impossible with regex basically. Of course it depends on project size, but IMO there are to many cases. HTML Tags, custom components, embedded text, mapped lists / components.

Comment: I would just do this one file at a time (manually) it's by far the safest, and I doubt another solution will automize the task with less time it takes to do it manually.....

Answer (score 3):

You can use the VS Code extension i18n Ally: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Lokalise.i18n-ally

I'm also working on a text extraction project and this has made things a lot faster. If you highlight static/hardcoded text there is a shortcut action you can use that prompts you to create a corresponding key for the text and moves the text to your json file, speeds things up a lot. I created a keyboard shortcut for it like so:

```
{
  "key": "shift+cmd+i",
  "command": "i18n-ally.extract-text"
}
```

Back to your immediate question, the extension has a beta feature for detecting hardcoded strings that is pretty useful. One issue I have with it is I can't figure out yet if there's a way to stop it from detecting inline CSS strings; it would be nice to ignore all that.

Some of the features are experimental/in beta so I can't vouch for it being error proof, but so far it's been very useful for me. Hope that's helpful.